# Why not use two indexes in the following sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (col1 INT, col2 INT);
ALTER TABLE test ADD INDEX idx_col1(col1);
ALTER TABLE test ADD INDEX idx_col2(col2);

EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test WHERE col1>=0 AND col2<=2;
```

Result:

```
id select_type table type  possible_keys        key key_len ref
1  SIMPLE      test  range idx_col2,idx_col1    idx_col2    5   1
```

Why only use idx_col2, not use both.

Comment: What type of SQL? How many records in your table? how many distinct values >0 in idx_col1? If an index doesn't appreciably reduce the records there's no point using it.

Comment: It is mysql, there 100m records, 850 thousands records in col1, the same with col2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic problem concerning selects which involve ranges.

The result of an index lookup is one or more rows in a table. When SQL decides how to process your select, it has to decide what index to use first. In your case it was idx_col2. As a result it will know all rows which satisfy (col2<=2).

From these rows it has to remove the ones which do no satisfy (col1>=0). However the index idx_col1 is of not much help here, because it refers to the *whole table* and not just to the rows which are still in question. An index range scan on idx_col1 would return *all* rows which satisfy the predicate and SQL would have to find rows which are found *both* by the col1 *and* col2 index range scan.

In virtually all cases this doesn't pay. If the number of rows returned from the col2 scan is small, then SQL might as well go through all these rows and check for (col1>=0) without using an index. If the number of rows is large, finding matching rows will be costly. It will have to consider all the rows returned from the col2 scan and check if there is a matching row in the col1 scan. This is more expensive than simply checking if they satisfy (col1>=0).

In general regular b-tree Indexes and ranges (concerning different columns) do not play together well. Some RDBMSs have a special kind of "spatial" index which allows efficient queries, which involve ranges.

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you use both it need to be sort twice,
it sort by col2, thus the remain lines are check line by line for col1,
Maybe this is because your rows are too small, if there are many rows, it might do sort twice, thus use 2 index.
I am not sure, just wondering.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember MySQL can use only one index to 1 table. *It's a feature...*

If you want use index for both columns you should use this:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD INDEX idx_cols(col1, col2);
```

This index should be correct to your query, but if you change order in query to `col2<=2 AND col1>=0` then the index can not be used...

Comment: the index always not be used, because the first column is a range column.